# Search by custom properties of Spatie Activity-log in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using [ActivityLog](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog) for logging my user's activities in Laravel. This package works really well in storing all the `create`, `update` and `delete` activities performed by the user on various models that I have setup with this package.

But there is one issue that I am facing now. I have the `ActivityLog` table like below-

```
id | log_name | description | subject_id | subject_type | causer_id | causer_type | properties
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7  | default  | created     |    4       | App\Response |   1       | App\User    |{"project_id":"22295","feature_id":"2","part_id":"1","response":"yes","user_id":1}
```

I need to get the results of this table filtered by `project_id` stored in the `properties` column. The package documentation says that `Activity` is a normal `Eloquent Model` so we can use all the `Eloquent` provided default functions to use with the `Activity` model. But I am not sure how to do this with `Eloquent`.

Right now, I am achieving this by the code below-

```
$activities = Activity::latest()->get()->filter(function($item) use($projectId) {
    $properties = $item->properties->toArray();
    if(isset($properties['attributes'])) 
        $properties = $properties['attributes'];

    return ($properties['project_id'] == $projectId);
});
```

The problem with my above code is that it fetches all the activities logged till date, so its loading all the `Activity` models which exists and then filters through based on the `project_id`. This will take alot of time when the size of the `ActivityLog` with increase to a large number, say 100,000 rows. Does anyone know a better way of fetching the filtered results based on `project_id` without going through all the rows manually?

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports JSON queries, you can do it.

```
$activities = Activity::where('properties->project_id', '22295')
            ->get();
```

Unfortunately, MariaDB as far as I know doesn't support that, so this only works if you're on MySQL 5.7.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/issues/210

However, if you *are* using MariaDB, you can create a virtual column based on the JSON data in the `properties` column and then index and query by that.

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102